# Multiple Early Bound Files in Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a WCF service with 3 different endpoints that need to use different Dynamics CRM early bound class files. I have them in separate namespaces, and have removed: `[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute()]` I can't seem to figure out how to specify which early bound file to use to when enabling proxy types. I am trying to avoid having each early bound file in a separate project. The files share some similar entities, but most importantly there are unique fields and entities that do not exist in the development organizations for the respective endpoints (endpoint 1 has entities that do not exist in endpoint 2).

Comment: How are you currently "Specifiying which early bound file to use"?

Comment: I have the endpoints in separate namespaces, and the early bound files in "sub namespaces". Namespace1, Namespace1.Helpers and Namespace2, Namespace2.Helpers. The endpoint classes are use the appropriate helper namespace, and I can access the appropriate entities/fields in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute defined in at least one file.  It doesn't matter what file actually, since it is an assembly attribute, not a class attribute.  You'll need to make sure that you don't attempt to use a type for an IOrganizationService call, that doesn't exist in that org.

**Update 1**

My understanding of the way the ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute works was wrong.  Apparently you can't have more than one class in the same assembly with the same  `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.EntityLogicalNameAttribute(string)` attribute (The string value has to be unique).

You have two possible solutions:

1. Create separate Assemblies.
2. Use the same namespace for both but don't duplicate classes by creating a class per entity for each CRM Org (This is where the https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/ becomes very helpful).  Any entities that exist in both, you'll have to either

   - Manually merge any differences (And when you're calling it, you'll have to know what is valid and what isn't valid for each Org! i.e. If Org 1's Contact entity has a ShirtSize field and Org 2 doesn't, you can't populate that attribute and attempt to insert into Org 2),
   - Use the file from one Org, and delete the other.

The second possible solution would work, but I don't think it's viable.

Comment: I added the ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute to my AssemblyInfo.cs file, but when I try to use a Linq query to access an entity that appears in only one of the early bound files I get the following:

`A proxy type with the name account has been defined by multiple types. Current type: Namespace1.Helpers.Account, RootNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Existing type: Namespace2.Helpers.Account, RootNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

I'm calling this from a class inside Namespace2, and uses Namespace2.Helpers

Comment: @SPride I've never actually done what you're proposing before, I just assumed it would work.  But your error is telling me something different than what I'm expecting.  Check out my update:

Comment: I ended up creating new projects/assemblies (like your first suggestion), in my service solution, for each early bound file, referenced the projects in the service, and used `proxy.EnableProxyTypes(Assembly.Load("EarlyBoundProjectName"))`. It's not exactly what I wanted to do, but it gets the job done. Thanks for the help!